# Is there a way to make an iframe to work as a link?

Tags: html, iframe

So, I have a web page I am working on, and the customer wants to make the embedded Google Maps iframe to open up Google Maps page when clicked.

As this isn't the default behavior of the embedded map itself, and wrapping the iframe between `<a></a>` tags doesn't help, I am completely clueless.

An example of an iframe in quesion, with my failed efforts of wrapping a link around it:

```html
<a href="https://goo.gl/maps/GsvZj4HWJwX1wc8fA" target="_blank">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1984.7094888859592!2d24.947179516385656!3d60.16898808196048!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x46920bcef71de10f%3A0x398a145b94611a7!2sAleksanterinkatu%2C%20Helsinki!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sfi!4v1617862310335!5m2!1sen!2sfi" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
</a>
```

My question is; how can one inject a link in to the iframe? As far as the normal functionality of the iframe is concerned, I think it matters not if it gets wiped.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an overlay(div) with 0 opacity on top of that iframe and can put that Overlay(div) inside your map link... (try this in your text editor it won't work here)

---

```css
.container{
      position: relative;
      width: min-content;
    }
.container .overlay{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1984.7094888859592!2d24.947179516385656!3d60.16898808196048!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x46920bcef71de10f%3A0x398a145b94611a7!2sAleksanterinkatu%2C%20Helsinki!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sfi!4v1617862310335!5m2!1sen!2sfi" width="500" height="300" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
        
        <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/GsvZj4HWJwX1wc8fA" target="_blank"><div class="overlay"></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually have an overlay in use for my project already, which seems like a great idea to make an extra use of. Thank you!

I will have to end up mixing solutions here though, because I can't directly add the link to my overlay wrapper without making it hardly accessible for possible updates (CMS issue), so I will use what Kashan suggested with your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Got you covered.

- Don't use links as the parents of big markup chunks, bad accessibility.
- Set `tabindex=1` on your `iframe`, which will make it focusable even by the keyboard.
- Assign an `id` to your iframe
- Set `data-href="your-link-to-maps"`, this is a custom HTML attribute and we'll use it in javascript.

Finally, add a click event listener.

```
function openMaps() {
    window.open(this.getAttribute('data-href'))
}

document.getElementById('my-iframe').addEventListener('click', openMaps)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I know it's not good for the accessibility, but this is one of the cases of "customer being right as always", sadly. I did the adds and odds you suggested, yet nothing happens when clicking the iframe. Even threw the `addEventListener` script inside of a `document.ready`, but this still left me hanging.